# unit sphere with respect to the max. norm is compact

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, compactness

Given $||x||_\infty=\max_i x_i$, where $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$, I want to show $\{x|\ ||x||_\infty=1\}$ is compact.

My try:

1) This set is closed, because it contains its boundary point $[1,...,1]$.

2) This set is bounded, because $|x|\leq \sqrt{n}$.

Is my proof acceptable?

Comment: You may need to change the title. "Maximum norm" can never be compact. It should be the "unit sphere with respect to the max. norm is compact".

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $x^{N}=(x_{N,1},...,x_{N,n})$ with $\|x^{N}\|_{\infty}=1$ and $x^{N}\rightarrow x=(x_{1},...,x_{n})$.

For $\epsilon>0$, choose an $n_{0}$ such that $\|x^{n_{0}}-x\|<\epsilon$, then $\|x\|\geq\|x^{n_{0}}\|-\|x^{n_{0}}-x\|=1-\epsilon$, and $\|x\|\leq\|x-x^{n_{0}}\|+\|x^{n_{0}}\|<\epsilon+1$, so $\|x\|=1$, this shows that the set is closed.

For boundedness, each $x$ with $\|x\|=1$ must satisfy $|x_{i}|\leq 1$ for each $i=1,...,n$, so $\|x\|_{2}^{2}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|\leq n$, so $\|x\|_{2}\leq\sqrt{n}$, as what you have written.

Comment: Is $\{x^N\}$ a sequence of vectors indexed by $N$?

Comment: Do you think my proof on boundedness is correct or not?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the idea is correct.

BUT: You need to show that the set contains ALL its boundary points, not just one!

You could also use the fact that the norm is continuous and that the preimage of the closed the $\{1\}$ so has to be closed too.

Comment: and I'm not sure about the bound either, it seems to be too small to me: 
with n=1 the bound 1 is not enough, I think you'd need $\sqrt{2}$